# Vue.js Mutator on Props - How do I apply standard logic to changes in a prop

Tags: vue.js

```
props: {
    user: {},
},
```

I have a `user` property which is a JSON string. I'd like to convert it to an object whenever it is changed via the prop value in my HTML.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

```
computed:{
    userObj(){
        return JSON.parse(this.user);
    }
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MpOaGL?editors=1010).